# Create Custom Variables within a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, variables, finance

I hope that you're doing well.

I'm kinda blocked on one part of my project. This a finance oriented project.

Basically, what I want is to loop through a dictionary of financial characteristics such as this:

```py
indices={'Revenues':revenue,'Cost Of Revenues':COGS,'Selling General & Admin Expenses':SGA,
         'R&D Expenses':RD,'Operating Income':OperatingIncome}
```

During my `for` loop, I wish to have just one line rather than doing this:

```
if count==1:
    prediction_revenue=finalpred
elif count==2:
    prediction_COGS=finalpred
elif count==3:
    prediction_SGA=finalpred
elif count==4:
    prediction_RDA=finalpred
else:
    prediction_operatingincome=finalpred[[key,'Date']]
```

Do you know how I could do that? That would greatly help me.

Comment: can you show more code? such as your whole `for-loop`

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea to generate variables. Proper pythonic way of doing this is to use a dictionary:

```
prediction = {}

if count==1:
    prediction['revenue'] = finalpred
elif count==2:
    prediction['COGS'] = finalpred
elif count==3:
    prediction['SGA'] = finalpred
elif count==4:
    prediction['RDA'] = finalpred
else:
    prediction['operatingincome'] = finalpred[[key,'Date']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to just assign finalpred to any key in your dictionary that's easy:

```
for prediction_name, prediction_value in indices:
    prediction_value = finalpred
```

You can iterate any dictionary like in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can access dictionary values through it's keys.

```
prediction['revenue'] = finalpred
prediction['COGS'] = finalpred
prediction['SGA'] = finalpred
prediction['RDA'] = finalpred
prediction['operatingincome'] = finalpred[[key,'Date']]
```